# Is it possible to prove the strong law of large numbers without the identically distributed condition using only a finite first moment assumption?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent, but not necessarily identically distributed. If we know that $E(X_n) = 0$, it is possible to show that $\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} \to_{a.s.} 0$ using only the assumption that the first moment, $E|X_n|$ is finite?

Comment: No. Let $X_n=f(n)B$ where $B$ is symmetric Bernoulli on $\{-1,1\}$ and $f(n)=\omega(n)$. You need further conditions on the variance.

Comment: Could I ask what $\omega(n)$ is here? Would you happen to have an example where it is indexed by $n$? Thanks.

Comment: $f(n)=\omega(n)$ means $\frac{f(n)}{n}\to \infty$. It is indexed by $n$.

Comment: Oh, so it is basically little-o notation?

Comment: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: Do you have a concrete example what $f(n)$ could be? or is this more or less a theoretical concept?

Comment: Take $f(n)=n^2$